# How to make a GitLab branch protected/unprotected using CLI

Tags: gitlab, command-line-interface

I've been trying to figure out how to get GitLab to protect or unprotect certain branches of certain projects without having to use the GUI. I have admin privileges for the GitLab, and have been trying to determine if it is even possible to enable/disable protections in some way other than following the "Settings" → "Repository" → "Expand" on "Protected branches" steps that require the web interface.

My end goal is to incorporate it into a more automated process so I don't have to go project to project protecting branches.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but since it's not a feature from git itself, you'll probably have to use GitLab's API, there's a reference for the Protected Branches API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#protect-repository-branch